# Retriew object in relational field on parse.com

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

i've created a table in parse called user and into there is a relational field friends pointing to the same table user.Now i've fetched by backbone the collection of user and i get a single user.How can i get the list of object contained into field friends?I've tried by get method backbone but it returns an object like this:Object {__type: "Relation", className: "_User"}.

```
 var cur_user = Parse.User.current().id;
   var self = this;
   Models.utenti = new Usercollection();
   Models.utenti.fetch({
       success: function (object) {
           var cur_user = Parse.User.current().id;
          // So this gives u a user Model
           var user = Models.utenti.get(cur_user);
           // Lets say the friends list is not a Collection yet
           // Assuming it's just an object
           var friends = user.get("friends"));
          // Create a Friends Collection
          var Collections.friends = New FriendCollection(friends);
           var view = new FriendsView({
               collection: Collections.friends
           });
           self.changePage(view);

       },
       error: function (amici, error) {
           console.log("don t work");
       }
```

Comment: What exactly are you returning in the response when the collection is fetched.. I hope it is the updated list of `Models.utenti` right ?

Comment: yes it returns the updated collection

Comment: Then why do you want to use the `Object` here you can access the collection directly.. And the list of fiends is a collection right.. Why do you wanna pass in as a Model.. Pass it as a collection

Comment: i don't understand can you make an example please?

Answer (score 0):

You need not use the object in the first place.. Can directly use the collection which is a Models collection of users.

So I wrote it this way assuming that there is a friends collection

```
 var friends = user.get("friends"));
  // Create a Friends Collection
   var Collections.friends = New FriendCollection(friends);
   var view = new FriendsView({
       collection: Collections.friends
   });
```

But if the friends is also a List of users then you can just create a `new UserCollection` from the friends object and then pass it to the View

```
var friends = user.get("friends"));
// Create a Friends Collection
var Collections.friends = New UserCollection(friends);
var view = new FriendsView({
     collection: Collections.friends
 });
```

---

```
var cur_user = Parse.User.current().id;
   var self = this;
   Models.utenti = new Usercollection();
   Models.utenti.fetch({
       success: function (object) {
           var cur_user = Parse.User.current().id;
          // So this gives u a user Model
           var user = Models.utenti.get(cur_user);
           // Lets say the friends list is not a Collection yet
           // Assuming it's just an object
           var friends = user.get("friends"));
          // Create a Friends Collection
           var Collections.friends = New FriendCollection(friends);
           var view = new FriendsView({
               collection: Collections.friends
           });
           self.changePage(view);

       },
       error: function (amici, error) {
           console.log("don t work");
       }
```

Comment: maybe you don't understand the problem

Comment: @StefanoMaglione.. If this is not the case can you explain your problem more clearly

Comment: friends is an attribute of user.This attribute in parse.com has relational type pointing to table user.So this attribute must be a list of object but console.log(friends) show this:Object {__type: "Relation", className: "_User"}

Comment: Check if you are passing an `Array of Objects` or a `Nested object`

Comment: First check how you are parsing and returning to the Front End.. Then open Developer tools in Chrome(Hit F12).. GO to the Network tab. Perform the action that fetches the collection. You can see the network. Click on the request and check the response section of that request

Comment: my render function in view want a collection,the problem is:how can i get collection by friends if friend is this:Object {__type: "Relation", className: "_User"}?My views want a collection like   this: child {length: 5, models: Array[5], _byId: Object, _byCid: Object, model: function…}

Comment: Can you paste how the object looks like here.. Looks like you are not populating the right data to the `friends` property

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34567/discussion-between-stefano-maglione-and-sushanth)